# Retriving Data Extension that WILL BE used as Send Target in a Scheduled Email by User Interface

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, schedule

when scheduling a "One Shot" email, we have to choose the data extensions that will be used as Target Send and The Exclusions Datas if need.

Is there a way to retrieve the data extension of that Send from that JOBID?

The send still has not been executed in this case.

And is not a Trigger Send or a Journey, is a Scheduled User Interface from Email Studio, the ones you can see in Email Studio--> Tracking --> Send --> MyTracking

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, it is not something simple you can do via JobID - but if you have the name or customerkey you can. You would need to utilize the SOAP API for this.

You would need to access the **[EmailSendDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/emailsenddefinition.html)** object and the **[DataExtension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dataextension.html)** object.

You would use a retrieve on EmailSendDefinition to be able to access the CustomObjectID (the internal unique identifier of the DE) and then use that to then retrieve the name/key from the DataExtension object via a filter.

So something like:

SOAP Envelope for EmailSendDefinition:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>EmailSendDefinition</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>SendDefinitionList</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>{{myEmailSendDefinitionCustomerKey}}</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and then you would take the `CustomObjectID` property from the `SendDefinitionList` section and then use that in the following example of a Retrieve on the DataExtension object:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
                <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>IsSendable</Properties>
                <Properties>SendableSubscriberField.Name</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>ObjectID</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>{{CustomObjectID}}</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Now if you only have the JobID and do not know the Name or Customerkey of the Email Send Definition, then there is an option for you to get it. You would need to use the **[Send](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/send.html)** object to get the customerkey. See below example envelope to accomplish this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>Send</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
                <Properties>EmailSendDefinition.CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>ID</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>{{JobID}}</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

You then take the CustomerKey returned and run through the above steps to get the DE that would be sent to.

Comment: Hi, could you doublecheck the second bit? If that works it would help me solve something, but when I try it with `<Properties>EmailSendDefinition.CustomerKey</Properties>` that gets accepted, as in, returns a response. Yet that response contains no trace of the send definition's customer key. other stuff like ID, Subject, EmailName etc. off the Send object work just fine. also tried it with `EmailSendDefinition.ObjectID` but no success. Thanks!

Comment: It is only for those that use EmailSendDefinitions, if it is sent via the Send Wizard, etc. then it will be empty.

Comment: got it, thanks!

Comment: @Gortonington, it is very helpfull to understand that for the "Send Wizard" it will be empty. Thank you.